# Is there any way to pass parameters to CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have done big research on that but nothing I could find as helpful result, is there any work around to pass arguments to CTE in Sql?
Or any alternative rather than using functions or views?
At least in new versions of Sql server?
Thank you

Comment: What would be the point?

Comment: You can create dynamic sql query and execute it with `sp_executesql`

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are thinking.   The answer is basically no.  And views don't accept arguments, so it is unclear what you are referring to there.

Comment: Example is building payment plan ( installment plan ) between two dates ( the CTE here would accept start and end of the period dates and the period between each installment as integer)

Comment: _alternative rather than using functions or views_ Why not a UDF? Every supported version of sql server supports those.

Comment: Dynamic Sql Might be fragile, I would prefer table function rather than dynamic Sql

Comment: A CTE doesn't need parameters. It can't exist on its own, it's always part of a query so it already has access to the query's parameters.

Comment: I have a database which have thousands of function with various naming styles over the years

Comment: I just don’t want add more functions to confuse the next developers

Comment: @Learner1111 what are you trying to do? What is the *actual* query you want to build? What you described doesn't need parameters.

Comment: Performance also another point I have to care which the function I believe slower

Comment: Your code bloat is your problem. No one but you can address that. But a UDF seems like the appropriate solution.

Comment: There is no only one query, there are many and I provided the installment as one example

Comment: It would be good if you provided a specific example in your question, with sample data / expected results, perhaps some pseudo-code of what you're imagining. Because currently it's still quite vague as to what precisely you are trying to do. As others have said, more than likely there is a better solution but first we need to get a clearer idea of the specifics.